# click all submit buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-console

I need to click all the submit button on a page so what I do ? in chrome console:

```
var  sumbits = jQuery(":submit");
for(var i =0; i<sumbits.length; i++) { 
     sumbits[i].click();
}
```

but the problem is only the last link clicked.
how do I achieve a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this

```
$("input[type='submit']").each(function(){
  $(this).trigger("click");
});
```

To trigger clicks on a delay youll have to trigger them from within a `setInterval` function.

```
var btns = $("input[type='submit']"),i=0,l = btns.length;
function clickLoop(){
  return setInterval(function(){
    btns[i].trigger('click');
    if(i>=l)
      clearInterval(fn);
    i++;
  },2000);
}
var fn = clickLoop();
```

Comment: still only the last one!

you can try here:
https://mrprintables.com/french-alphabet-coloring-pages/

Comment: I dont get it . Why do you want to trigger clicks on submit buttons? @OussamaELIssaoui

Comment: Then you might have to trigger clicks with a delay.

Comment: yeah I try timeout function but no way

Comment: @OussamaELIssaoui I have edited my answer. Try increasing the interval duration if it still doesnt work.